# Exclude a specific version pattern in renovate

Tags: maven, dependency-management, renovate

I have a maven project which depends of `com.thoughtworks.xstream:xstream:1.4.11.1`.

Renovate opened a pull request for `com.thoughtworks.xstream:xstream:1.4.12-java7` but I would prefer to see an pull request with `com.thoughtworks.xstream:xstream:1.4.12` since I am using Java 8.

How can I configure my renovate.json file to specify that, for the groupId `com.thoughtworks.xstream` and the artifactId `xstream`, I do not want to receive PR when the version ends with `-java7`?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

As documented upstream on https://docs.renovatebot.com/configuration-options/#packagerules, you could use a package rule with a negated regex to ignore certain versions, e.g.:

```json
{
  "packageRules": [
    {
      "matchPackageNames": ["com.thoughtworks.xstream:xstream"],
      "allowedVersions": "!/\\-java7$/"
    }
  ]
}
```

EDIT: actually taking a deeper look at the docs, they actually have samples with exactly this package, which makes me think that you actually asked this to the devs somewhere else and then they added the documented approach