# Exclude version pattern from renovate

Tags: maven, dependency-management, renovate

There are several standard Java dependencies that have forks with the same maven coordinates and a "redhat-xxx" suffix in their version number, for example

- [commons-configuration:common-configuration](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/commons-configuration/commons-configuration?repo=redhat-ga)
- [org.eclipse.microprofile.config:microprofile-config-api](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.eclipse.microprofile.config/microprofile-config-api?repo=redhat-ga)
- [javax.enterprise:cdi-api](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/javax.enterprise/cdi-api?repo=redhat-ga)

My question is

> (How) can I configure renovate to exclude *all* dependencies whose version matches `/redhat-\d+$/` ?

There is a similar question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61211875/exclude-a-specific-version-pattern-in-renovate), but that asks for a more restricted set of dependencies. If I were to define a packageRule like

```
{
  "packageRules": [
    {
      "groupName" : "Exclude all redhat-xyz versions"
      "matchPackagePatterns": [".*"],
      "allowedVersions": "!/redhat-\\d+$/"
    }
  ]
}
```

It would group **all** dependencies into one giant pull request which isn't helpful.

Answer (score 3):

Try to set `registryUrls` to standard Maven repo so that Redhat dependencies and such are not checked:

```
{
  "$schema": "https://docs.renovatebot.com/renovate-schema.json",
  "extends": ["config:base"],
  "packageRules": [{
    "matchManagers": ["maven"],
    "registryUrls": ["https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2"],
  }]
}
```

or use your given config and add `"enabled": false`