# Prevent renovate from updating not semantically versioned dependecies to -SNAPSHOT

Tags: renovate

Renovate updates

```
<dependency>
  <groupId>org.spockframework</groupId>
  <artifactId>spock-core</artifactId>
  <version>2.4-M1-groovy-4.0</version>
  <scope>test</scope>
</dependency>
```

to

```
<dependency>
  <groupId>org.spockframework</groupId>
  <artifactId>spock-core</artifactId>
  <version>2.4-groovy-4.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
  <scope>test</scope>
</dependency>
```

which is not what we want. SNAPSHOT-versions should be skipped.

I played around with the solution from [Exclude version pattern from renovate](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70831503/exclude-version-pattern-from-renovate) but couldn't get it to work.

Both of these do not work

```
  "packageRules": [
    {
      "matchPackagePrefixes": ["org.spockframework"],
      "allowedVersions": "!/\\-snapshot$/"
    }
  ]
```

and

```
  "packageRules": [
    {
      "matchPackageNames": ["org.spockframework:spock-core", "org.spockframework:spock-spring"],
      "allowedVersions": "!/\\-snapshot$/"
    }
  ]
```

Before trying further - what would be the right way of doing it?
Does the regex need to be a full match? Is it case-sensitive?

Comment: Do you have a specific config? I believe it only does so if told to. Otherwise by default, Renovate ignores SNAPSHOT versions. This might be related to the fact that you were already using a `M1` version considered as "beta" as well.

Comment: See https://github.com/renovatebot/renovate/discussions/22092#discussioncomment-5873377

Comment: Anyway, look at  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61211875/exclude-a-specific-version-pattern-in-renovate for a working example

Comment: @GaëlJ no special configuration here. I guessed it must be the unorthodox version present (2.4-M1-groovy-4.0) that makes renovate update to a snapshot-version (or any other version containing any characters, it seems).