# How to add Renovate Bot packagerule for Maven minor update only for jre11 version

Tags: java, renovate

I want to do minor update for Java Maven with Renovate Bot for
`<mssql.jdbc.version>11.2.1.jre11\</mssql.jdbc.version>`.
Renovate Bot updating to 11.x.x version, but changes the version from jre11 to jre18.

Initial version:  `<mssql.jdbc.version>11.2.1.jre11</mssql.jdbc.version>`
Upgraded version: `<mssql.jdbc.version>11.2.3.jre18</mssql.jdbc.version>`

How can we check for jre11 version and create rule for PR creation to version update which consist jre11 and not jre18 or other version?

I tried below regex and conditions, but I'm unable to filter out jre18 from version upgrade.

```yaml
packageRules: [{
    "managers": \["maven"\],
    "depName": "com.microsoft.sqlserver:mssql-jdbc",
    "matchPackagePatterns": \[ "^@mssql-jdbc" \],
    "matchCurrentVersion": "/\[\\.-\]jre11\\d+$/",
    "newValue": "/jre11$/"
}]
```

```yaml
{  
    "matchCurrentVersion": "/\[\\.-\]redhat-\\d+$/",
    "allowedVersions": "/\[\\.-\]redhat-\\d+$/"
}
```

```yaml
{
    "managers": \["maven"\],
    "matchPackagePatterns": \[ "^@mssql-jdbc" \],
    "allowedVersions": "/.jre11$/"
}
```

```yaml
{
    "allowedVersions": "/^(?jre11)(?:\\.|-|$)/"  
}
```

```yaml
{
    "allowedVersions": "/.\*jre11/"    
}
```

I followed some below links:

- https://github.com/renovatebot/renovate/discussions/9346
- https://github.com/renovatebot/renovate/issues/5303

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Exclude a specific version pattern in renovate](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61211875/exclude-a-specific-version-pattern-in-renovate)

Comment: mssql-jdbc has 3 minor versions upgrade for 11.x. 
11.2.3.jre18 
11.2.3.jre17 
11.2.3.jre11
Renovatebot skips jre11 and jre17 and attempting PR for jre18 version.
If I add condition for jre11 in packagerule, renovatebot ignores it. If adding condition to exclude jre18 version, Renovatebot match condition and does not create PR for mssql-jdbc.
How can we create PR for specific version.

Answer (score 0):

I tried below packagerule and it worked for me in config.js..

```
{
  "matchPackageNames": ["com.microsoft.sqlserver:mssql-jdbc"],
  "allowedVersions": "/\.jre11$/"
}
```